# Spring Boot App Fails to Start on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to run my Spring Boot + MySQL app on Elastic Beanstalk.  No matter what I try I get the `502 Bad Gateway`.  I have tried changing my Spring Boot port to 5000, but it does not seem to help at all.

I have tried adding `server.port=5000` in `application.properties`.  I have also tried adding `server.port=${PORT}`.

Every time I `eb deploy` the logs show this:

```
03:08:21.096 [main] INFO  t.t.TrackMyWaterChangeApplication - Starting TrackMyWaterChangeApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on ip-172-31-41-134 with PID 6105 (/var/app/current/application.jar started by webapp in /var/app/current)
03:08:21.098 [main] INFO  t.t.TrackMyWaterChangeApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
03:08:54.024 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
03:08:56.577 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2305ms. Found 4 repository interfaces.
03:09:20.544 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c95c6ba6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
03:09:35.665 [main] INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
03:09:36.122 [main] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-5000"]
03:09:36.533 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
03:09:36.533 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
03:09:39.127 [main] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
03:09:39.128 [main] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 75522 ms
03:09:59.224 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
03:10:08.318 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
03:10:08.880 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
03:10:08.889 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
03:10:09.268 [main] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
03:10:10.046 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
03:10:12.003 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
03:10:13.291 [main] INFO  o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
03:10:14.039 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
03:10:14.041 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
03:10:14.049 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
03:10:14.063 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

My assumption is that the app never starts because of the last line (`o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]`).  It works when I run locally when I set the port to 5000.  To deploy the app I use `mvn clean package` and then `eb deploy`.  If I run the packaged JAR from the command line on my Windows PC, it runs no problem.  This is the `<build>` portion of my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>themayoras</groupId>
    <artifactId>trackmywaterchange</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>trackmywaterchange</name>
    <description>Web Project for tracking water change schedules</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AOP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- SL4FJ Logging -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

edit: I am getting a new log message under `/var/log/nginx/error.log` that reads

```
Professional SP1 x64|'|'|No|'|'|0.7d|'|'|..|'|'|AA==|'|'|112.inf|'|'|SGFjS2VkDQoxOTIuMTY4LjkyLjIyMjo1NTUyDQpEZXNrdG9wDQpjbGllbnRhLmV4ZQ0KRmFsc2UNCkZhbHNlDQpUcnVlDQpGYWxzZQ==12.act|'|'|AA=="
2019/08/11 16:48:57 [error] 1293#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 35.21.86.49, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "trackmywaterchange.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/08/11 16:48:57 [error] 1293#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 35.21.86.49, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "trackmywaterchange.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://trackmywaterchange.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

logs under `/var/logs/nginx/error.log`

```
2019/08/11 03:16:33 [error] 6663#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 35.21.86.49, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "trackmywaterchange.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://trackmywaterchange.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2019/08/11 05:40:09 [warn] 6663#0: *4 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 194.32.117.3, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 05:40:09 [warn] 6663#0: *4 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 194.32.117.3, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 05:40:09 [warn] 6663#0: *4 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 194.32.117.3, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 05:40:09 [warn] 6663#0: *4 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 194.32.117.3, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 13:26:14 [warn] 6663#0: *26 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 164.132.153.130, server: , request: "CONNECT i.instagram.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 13:26:14 [warn] 6663#0: *26 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 164.132.153.130, server: , request: "CONNECT i.instagram.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 13:26:14 [warn] 6663#0: *26 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 164.132.153.130, server: , request: "CONNECT i.instagram.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 13:26:14 [warn] 6663#0: *26 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 164.132.153.130, server: , request: "CONNECT i.instagram.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:49 [warn] 6663#0: *33 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:49 [warn] 6663#0: *33 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:49 [warn] 6663#0: *33 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:49 [warn] 6663#0: *33 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:50 [warn] 6663#0: *32 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:50 [warn] 6663#0: *32 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:50 [warn] 6663#0: *32 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:50 [warn] 6663#0: *32 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:58 [warn] 6663#0: *34 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:58 [warn] 6663#0: *34 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:58 [warn] 6663#0: *34 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:30:58 [warn] 6663#0: *34 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:31:06 [warn] 6663#0: *35 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:31:06 [warn] 6663#0: *35 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:31:06 [warn] 6663#0: *35 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:31:06 [warn] 6663#0: *35 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 110.249.212.46, server: , request: "GET http://110.249.212.46/testget?q=23333&port=80 HTTP/1.1"
2019/08/11 14:33:45 [warn] 6663#0: *36 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 66.240.205.34, server: , request: "145.ll|'|'|SGFjS2VkX0Q0OTkwNjI3|'|'|WIN-JNAPIER0859|'|'|JNapier|'|'|19-02-01|'|'||'|'|Win 7 Professional SP1 x64|'|'|No|'|'|0.7d|'|'|..|'|'|AA==|'|'|112.inf|'|'|SGFjS2VkDQoxOTIuMTY4LjkyLjIyMjo1NTUyDQpEZXNrdG9wDQpjbGllbnRhLmV4ZQ0KRmFsc2UNCkZhbHNlDQpUcnVlDQpGYWxzZQ==12.act|'|'|AA=="
2019/08/11 14:33:45 [warn] 6663#0: *36 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 66.240.205.34, server: , request: "145.ll|'|'|SGFjS2VkX0Q0OTkwNjI3|'|'|WIN-JNAPIER0859|'|'|JNapier|'|'|19-02-01|'|'||'|'|Win 7 Professional SP1 x64|'|'|No|'|'|0.7d|'|'|..|'|'|AA==|'|'|112.inf|'|'|SGFjS2VkDQoxOTIuMTY4LjkyLjIyMjo1NTUyDQpEZXNrdG9wDQpjbGllbnRhLmV4ZQ0KRmFsc2UNCkZhbHNlDQpUcnVlDQpGYWxzZQ==12.act|'|'|AA=="
2019/08/11 14:33:45 [warn] 6663#0: *36 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 66.240.205.34, server: , request: "145.ll|'|'|SGFjS2VkX0Q0OTkwNjI3|'|'|WIN-JNAPIER0859|'|'|JNapier|'|'|19-02-01|'|'||'|'|Win 7 Professional SP1 x64|'|'|No|'|'|0.7d|'|'|..|'|'|AA==|'|'|112.inf|'|'|SGFjS2VkDQoxOTIuMTY4LjkyLjIyMjo1NTUyDQpEZXNrdG9wDQpjbGllbnRhLmV4ZQ0KRmFsc2UNCkZhbHNlDQpUcnVlDQpGYWxzZQ==12.act|'|'|AA=="
2019/08/11 14:33:45 [warn] 6663#0: *36 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 66.240.205.34, server: , request: "145.ll|'|'|SGFjS2VkX0Q0OTkwNjI3|'|'|WIN-JNAPIER0859|'|'|JNapier|'|'|19-02-01|'|'||'|'|Win 7 Professional SP1 x64|'|'|No|'|'|0.7d|'|'|..|'|'|AA==|'|'|112.inf|'|'|SGFjS2VkDQoxOTIuMTY4LjkyLjIyMjo1NTUyDQpEZXNrdG9wDQpjbGllbnRhLmV4ZQ0KRmFsc2UNCkZhbHNlDQpUcnVlDQpGYWxzZQ==12.act|'|'|AA=="
2019/08/11 16:48:57 [error] 1293#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 35.21.86.49, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "trackmywaterchange.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/08/11 16:48:57 [error] 1293#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 35.21.86.49, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "trackmywaterchange.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://trackmywaterchange.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    32793;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        listen        80 default_server;
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        client_header_timeout 60;
        client_body_timeout   60;
        keepalive_timeout     60;
        gzip                  off;
        gzip_comp_level       4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bring down the logging level to DEBUG and see if it helps

Comment: @YatiSawhney I have set `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` in `application.properties` and I receive the same output.

I do get a new logging message for `/var/log/nginx/error.log` that I have added to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache as proxy

Comment: @YatiSawhney I am using nginx

Comment: Upload Nginx logs as well. They are generally stored in /var/log/nginx

Comment: I believe I added the logs

Comment: can you add your full pom file in question

Comment: Nginx Config please

Comment: I do not have an Nginx Config... how can I create one?

Comment: Check `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` All you got to do is enable the port 5000 there

Comment: If I use `eb ssh`, it says neither of those files exist.  I added the config contents from `/etc/nginx/nginx.config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up failing on a database connection.

If you notice in the log, there is this line:

```
03:10:13.291 [main] INFO  o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

As it turns out, the startup fails after this step.  Unfortunately there isn't a good error message describing what is wrong, but after a lot of testing, I found that it was due to a failure to connect to the database.

Here are the basic troubleshooting steps that I took.

1. Verify locally:

   This should go without saying, but shut down your local database and try to start your app.  If it fails, then you've got your issue, otherwise this is not your root cause.
2. Verify all spelling:

   Again, this should go without saying, but after figuring out the issue, check your spelling.  For example, I was using this as my datasource url in my application.properties
   `jdbc:mysql://${MSYQL_HOST:test_host}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/${MYSQL_DB:test_db}`.  If you look carefully, you will notice that my `MYSQL_HOST` environment variable is spelled wrong.
3. SSH and Check you Connection

   Try to connect to your database after ssh'ing into your environment.  After doing `yum install MySQL`, use this command: `MySQL -h 'rds-endpoint-url' -P 'rds-DB-port' -u 'db-username' -p`.  After entering the connection password, you should enter a `MySQL` prompt. If not, check that your RDS instance is in the same VPC as your ec2 or elb instance and allows the security group that your ec2 or elb instance has.

After all is said and done, these general steps will hopefully resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

seems like following dependancy is missing in your pom  ,could you plz update full pom in question ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: full pom.xml added